# Why javascript ( Tested on Chrome and Firefox ) return invalid value when doing basic mathematical operation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I was in the middle doing some projects, an surprisingly i found something weird happen in javascript.

why :

-1 * 0 = -0 and 0 == -0 return true ? ( tested in chrome and firefox )

Anyone can explain ?

Any help really appreciated

Comment: Do you really expect `-0 == 0` to return false?

Comment: theoretically, yes.

Comment: they are both true.` -1 * 0` DOES equal `-0` so that is correct.  `0` and `-0` are the same, the value of each is still `0`.... and you are comparing the value of them with `==` operator, so it is also correct :)

Comment: interesting. just checked that 0 === -0 return true too. so basically 0 and -0 is same value and same type

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what about -1 * 0 = -0 ? isn't it should be 0 ?

Comment: also you are correct... `==` checks value, while `===` checks both value and type

Comment: "The rule for multiplying and dividing is very similar to the rule for adding and subtracting. When the signs are different the answer is negative. When the signs are the same the answer is positive."

Comment: Well, thanks for help guys.

Comment: @ErdoDirgagautama The accepted answer on the linked question explains that `===` is explicitly designed to ignore the sign if the value is `0` or `-0`.